# Procedure to Union All tables in a database (MySql)

Tags: sql, mysql, stored-procedures

I want to insert the union of all tables in a database (ALARM_XX_*) in a new table (ALARM_XX_ALL) but the cursor that allows me to iterate over my database (db) is always NUUL, even if the query in the declare statement returns non empty values (it returns ALARM_XX_2022_03_01, ALARM_XX_2022_03_02, ALARM_XX_2022_03_03...) .

```
DELIMITER //
drop procedure if exists union_all_tables //
CREATE PROCEDURE union_all_tables()
BEGIN
  DECLARE sql_query VARCHAR(1000);
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE table_name VARCHAR(255);
  
  -- Create a cursor to iterate over the tables matching the pattern
  DECLARE tables_cursor CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT table_name 
    FROM information_schema.tables 
    WHERE table_schema = 'db' 
    AND table_name NOT LIKE 'ALARM_XX_2023_01_%' 
    AND table_name NOT LIKE 'ALARM_XX_2023_02_%' 
    AND table_name LIKE 'ALARM_XX_2022%' or table_name LIKE 'ALARM_XX_2023%';
    
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
  
  -- All of ALARM_XX_* have the same structure (same columns)
  CREATE TABLE ALARM_XX_ALL LIKE db.ALARM_XX_2022_03_01;
  
  -- Open the cursor and loop through the tables
  OPEN tables_cursor;
  tables_loop: LOOP
    FETCH tables_cursor INTO table_name;
    IF done THEN
      select 'cursor is NULL maybe ??';
      LEAVE tables_loop;
    END IF;
    
    -- Build the SQL query to UNION ALL the data from the tables
    SET @sql_query = CONCAT('INSERT INTO ALARM_XX_ALL SELECT * FROM ', table_name);
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql_query;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
  END LOOP;
  
  -- Close the cursor
  CLOSE tables_cursor;
  
  -- Return the result of the UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM ALARM_XX_ALL limit 10;
  
END//

DELIMITER ;

-- call stored procedure
call union_all_tables ;
```

Can you please help me out ? Thank you so much.

When calling the procedure , the loop always ends because I think the cursor is NULL.

PS : I am not the one who built this database this way .

Comment: Why do you have so many ALARM_XX_ tables? Can't you have just one instead?

Comment: I totally agree with you, I am not the one who built this database this way :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the name of the variable where you fetch, it should work.